# Running cron results in Caches Flushed

Tags: 6, caching, cron

I am unable to run cron on a Drupal 6.25 web site.

Running cron using both the **run cron** option from administration menu and the **run cron manually** link from **status report** page results in the following message:

```
Caches flushed.
```

The warning message next to the **cron maintenance tasks** entry on the status report persists and cron hasn't run.

I recently upgraded to latest version of Drupal. This issue also affects development copy of web site.

As always, I ran update.php after upgrade - no errors reported.

Tried changing number of items at /admin/settings/search to 10.

Can anyone advise how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the PHP filter module, as per suggestions below solved the problem:

http://drupal.org/node/123269#comment-5696238

However, ultimately I believe the issue was caused by illegal mix of collations error.

Changing the collation of all table to utf8_unicode_ci using MySQL Workbench solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[`system_cron`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_cron/6) calls [`cache_clear_all`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) with `$cid == NULL`, which should just be clearing out expired entries.

My *guess* is that something else is wrong with the system, and cron is failing as a result.

When you upgraded, did you make sure you ran `update.php`?

Do you see cron listed as being run in watchdog (/admin/reports/dblog)?

Are there any php or other errors/warnings in watchdog around the cron run?

What does your search index status say (/admin/settings/search)?  cron will index search each run.  If this takes too long, you may have problems.  Try dropping down the number of items per run.

If you run `drush cron` from the command line, does it run properly?

Comment: Updated original question. Thanks for your help - the following error is present in dblog: http://pastebin.com/KDGrUzNV. Perhaps this is the issue. I shall install drush and try clearing cache from shell.

Comment: Googling for that error message brings up a ton of posts on various forums.  Something is wrong in your database.

Comment: Indeed. Altered all tables to `utf8_unicode_ci` collation. New cron error logged: `Cron run exceeded the time limit and was aborted.`. Increased `max_execution_time` from 60 to 120 in php.ini, to no avail.

Comment: Did you remember to restart Apache?  Did you look at the search index thing?